# What is the complexity of removing elements from array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, time-complexity

What is the time complexity when removing elements from an array? Specifically, what is the complexity when removing the last element using [`array.pop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pop)?

Comment: Removing the last element should be O(1) since nothing needs to be moved around. Removing other elements is probably O(n) because the remaining elements have to be shifted.

Comment: @Stefan By that logic, removing the k-th from the last should be O(1) (for constant k). Removing the k-th from the first should be O(n).

Comment: @Stefan Yes. That is what I wrote. I was mentioning your "Removing other elements is probably O(n)" part, which I may have took it not as you intended. The point is that, the complexity depends not on the position, but on how it is counted.

Comment: @Stefan looks like calling shift is also fast - ruby increments the pointer rather than moving all the data.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how Ruby stores arrays internally. There seems to be a difference between small (`ARY_EMBED_P`) and large (`ARY_SHARED_P`) arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its `O(1)`.

Source: [array.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L949)

```
VALUE
rb_ary_pop(VALUE ary)
{
  long n;
  rb_ary_modify_check(ary);
  n = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
  if (n == 0) return Qnil;
  if (ARY_OWNS_HEAP_P(ary) && 
      n * 3 < ARY_CAPA(ary) &&
      ARY_CAPA(ary) > ARY_DEFAULT_SIZE)
  {
    ary_resize_capa(ary, n * 2);
  }
  --n;
  ARY_SET_LEN(ary, n);
  return RARRAY_AREF(ary, n);
}
```

As you can see, it simply decrements the length of the array and returns value at that index. Occasionally, a pop might trigger a resize which would be `O(n)`